# Css container no grow same time when resize content inside

Tags: css

**You can test CSS here :**

https://jsfiddle.net/razp9f0k/

Ok, the problem in my css it´s the next, i have container called **win_container_gen**, this container have inside other divs in relative position amd the div inside called **win_container** , change his height and width, the first you can see when load demo site with this css example it´s div with border in black, and this it´s the general container and as you can see this container it´s more smaller than content inside, the problem it´s with the height

I try fix this usind height auto, also with max-height, etc, but result it´s the same, the general container don´t grow same time with the content inside

I don´t know if exists some trick for this, but my question it´s this

How i can do for  general container grow same time and with the same height as inside content for don´t show more smaller tha containers inside

```css
#win_container_gen {
  position:relative;
  width:350px;
  height:300px;
  margin:auto;
  border:4px solid #111;
}

#win_title {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:35px;
  line-height:35px;
  margin:auto;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#fff;
  padding-left:1%;
  background-color:#111;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

#win_container {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border:0px solid;
  background-color:#eee;
}


#win_footer {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
  background-color:grey;
  bottom:0;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

#iframe {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="win_container_gen">

<div id="win_title"></div>

<div id="win_container">
<iframe src="http://brute-power.com" width="0" marginwidth="0" height="0" marginheight="0"  scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" id="iframe"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="win_footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you defined `height:100%` on the inner element BUT you have more elements so the total height of all the elements will exceed 100% thus you have the overflow. An easy fix to this is to rely on flexbox and instead of `height:100%` you use `flex:1` to make the inner container fill the remaining space left by the other elements:

```css
#win_container_gen {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  border: 4px solid #111;
}

#win_title {
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 1%;
  background-color: #111;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

#win_container {
  flex: 1;
  border: 0px solid;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#win_footer {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
  background-color: grey;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

#iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="win_container_gen">

  <div id="win_title"></div>

  <div id="win_container">
    <iframe src="http://brute-power.com" width="0" marginwidth="0" height="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" id="iframe"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div id="win_footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternately, use height: calc(100% - 75px); on the win_container. 75px is the height of the two other divs inside win_container_gen. Flexbox seems the most flexible, though :)